# Delphi 11.2 How to set breakpoint when tbitbtn change enabled=true to enanbled=false

Tags: debugging, delphi, breakpoints

I cant see in code when a Tbitbtn change the value from enabled=true to =false.

Can I use the address of the bitbtn and add that a  address breakpoint  with condition bitbtn.enabled=false?

Or how to to do?

Whenever bitbtn.enabled become false I want the program to stop..

Comment: That's called a conditional breakpoint.  Right-click on your breakpoint, then Breakpoint Properties.  There you'll see a Condition box.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14164631/how-to-define-a-breakpoint-whenever-an-object-field-value-changes

Comment: The  disabling is happening in the code somewhere I cant see where it is. So the breakpoint must be detecting when  memory  change, not when line is passed

Comment: You want an event-driven debugger.